# getSiteURL PHP Class

Tags: php, oop, server

I'm building a class for a CRM application, and I have to make a public function to call for site url. This is my approach, but I get an error...

```
<?php
    class idkCRM {

                public function __construct($db_con) {
                    $this->db = $db_con;
                }

                private $use_forwarded_host = false;


                private function url_org( $s, $use_forwarded_host ) {

                    $ssl = (!empty($s['HTTPS'] ) && $s['HTTPS'] == 'on' );
                    $sp = strtolower($s['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] );
                    $protocol = substr($sp, 0, strpos($sp, '/')) . ( ( $ssl ) ? 's' : '' );
                    $port = $s['SERVER_PORT'];
                    $port = ( ( ! $ssl && $port=='80' ) || ($ssl && $port =='443' ) ) ? '' : ':'.$port;
                    $host = ( $use_forwarded_host && isset ( $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] ) ) ? $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] : ( isset( $s['HTTP_HOST'] ) ? $s['HTTP_HOST'] : null );
                    $host = isset ( $host ) ? $host : $s['SERVER_NAME'] . $port;

                    return $protocol. '://' .$host;
                }

                public function full_url( $s, $use_forwarded_host=false ) {
                    return url_org( $s, $use_forwarded_host ) . $s['REQUEST_URI'];
                }

                public function getUrl ( $s, $use_forwarded_host=false ) {
                    return url_org ( $s, $use_forwarded_host ) ;
                }

            }
?>
```

So I should call for my function like this?

```
$absolute_url = full_url( $_SERVER );
echo $absolute_url;

$url = getUrl( $_SERVER );
echo $url;
```

Comment: And _what_ error do you get?

Comment: You probably man `return $this->url_org(...);`, not `return url_org(...);`.

Comment: $obj = new idkCRM(); $absolute_url = $obj->full_url( $_SERVER );

Comment: Call to undefined method idk::getUrl()

Comment: @arkascha thanks mate, makes more sense dough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the function from within the same class then you have to use

`$this->yourfunction();` otherwise you need to create a new idkCRM instance like this:

```
$crm = new idkCRM($dbcon);
$crm->yourfunction();
```

Comment: I'm pretty much sure how to call a function, $crm is being called only once, so there is no need to create a new instance... CP my code and test it, I get undefined method error.

Comment: The problem was there was no $dbcon due to driver issues ( PDOdriver ), so construct function was not passing the obj to the class... Anyway thanks mate